# Как предотвратить создание компонента?

Tags: vue.js

Нужно чтобы компонент создавался только после ajax запросов.
Можно ли вызвав метод beforeCreate остановить дальнейшее выполнение?

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    components: {
        App
    },
    template: '<App/>',
    beforeCreate() {

        fb.initializeApp({
        });

        fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            if(user){   
                this.$store.dispatch('autoLoginUser' , user.uid)
            }
        })

    }
})
```

Comment: инициализацию компонента вы не предотвратите, но можете обернуть компонент в `v-if`, в дата определить свойство `loaded: false`, проделать какие-то асинхронные таски с `facebook sdk` и присвоить `this.$data.loaded = true`, самое быстрое и элегантное решение

Comment: В общем случае ещё можно [загрузжать данные перед переходом роутера](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#загрузка-данных-перед-переходом)